# UPDATE LEFT JOIN taking a long time to execute

Tags: postgresql, nested-loops, upsert

I noticed that the query below was taking more than 70s on a 5000 row table:

```sql
UPDATE union_suppliers
SET
    supp_date_update=sd.last_sync
FROM union_suppliers us
    LEFT JOIN source_duns sd
        ON us.source_duns_uuid = sd.uuid
WHERE coalesce(sd.last_sync > us.supp_date_update, TRUE);
```

I ran the query with `ANALYZE` and was surprised to see that I'd created a nested loop:

[image]

I can't understand why this is.  I've now aliased and joined the table in the where clause like so, but all rows are updated, irrespective of the `coalesce(sd.last_sync > uso.supp_date_update, TRUE)`:

```sql
UPDATE union_suppliers us
SET
    supp_date_update=sd.last_sync
FROM union_suppliers uso
    LEFT JOIN source_duns sd
        ON uso.source_duns_uuid = sd.uuid
WHERE uso.uuid = us.uuid 
    and coalesce(sd.last_sync > uso.supp_date_update, TRUE);
```

[image]

My questions are:

- why was this making a nested loop?
- why is the second query different, it seems on the surface that I'm doing the same thing?
- why are all rows updated in the second case?

Comment: You are aware that the `union_suppliers` you are `UPDATE`ing is a separate table alias from that in your `FROM` clause? As in "cross join" separate?

Comment: `FROM union_suppliers uso` <<-- don't repeat the target table in the `FROM` clause. [must be a duplicate] (BTW: the LEFT JOIN makes little sense to me)

Comment: @RichardHuxton thanks for the response, you mean that there's a cross join in the first example or in the second?

Comment: first one. You re-join in the second one so I guess that should be fine (I'm assuming "uuid" is unique on that table). Thatdoes make the repetition of the table pointless of course. I can't quite figure out what the query is intended to do. The coalesce seems a clumsy way to handle `OR IS NULL` and I don't see why you'd want to update if `last_sync` was null either.